# code not working when checking table row count

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a table of search results when the user presses the search button.  I am doing this, so that the table is cleared of previous search results if any are present.

However, the code doesn't work.  Nothing happens when the user presses search.  If I remove or comment out the code, then it works fine.

Here is my code that is causing issues:

```
            var rowCount = $(this + " tr").length;
            if (rowCount > 1) {
                alert("true");
                $(this + " tr").remove();
            }
            ...go on to populate table with search results....
```

thanks

Comment: `$(this + " tr")` is the same as `$("[object Object] tr")`, i'm sure you can now see why that doesn't select your table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not concatenate an object with a string, the selector will be `"[object Object] tr"`, use `$('selector', context)` instead:

```
var rowCount = $("tr", this).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$(this).find("tr")`

instead of

`$(this + " tr")`